# Getting ENOENT while starting meteor in Raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, meteor, raspberry-pi

I have installed meteor in my raspberry pi but i am unable to run.Checked all the processes as well running on 3000. Uploading the image for reference.[image]

Comment: is this a "clean" app (just created via meteor create?) if not, does this also occur when starting a newly created app?

Comment: It was not created via meteor create, I have copied this meteor project from my another linux machine. But even if i create a new app via meteor create same error is occuring.